# Cross Apply where customer doesn't have email address

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example Dataset:

dbo.Customer

```
 CustomerId | SignUpDate | LastContactDate
 123        | 23/08/2017 | 02/04/2018
 456        | 30/12/2017 | 20/02/2018
```

dbo.CustomerUsers

```
 CustomerId | UserId | Name              | Primary | EmailAddress
 123        | 1777   | Alexander Bailey  | 1       | a.bailey@example.com
 123        | 1778   | Linda Bailey      | 0       | NULL
 456        | 2554   | Jeff Banks        | 1       | NULL
 456        | 3100   | Shiniqua Banks    | 0       | NULL
```

I would like to return all customers where the CustomerUsers DO NOT have an email address at all. If either or both CustomerUsers have an email, do not return.

I have done the reverse as this:

```
        SELECT
            c.CustomerId,
            cu.EmailAddress
        FROM
            dbo.Customers c
        CROSS APPLY
            (SELECT TOP(1) EmailAddress 
            FROM Tenants.TenantClient 
            WHERE AND CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
            ORDER BY c.IsPrimary DESC) cu
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Customer C
     JOIN CustomerUser CU ON C.CustomerID = CU.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN EmailAddress IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

No need for 2 scans of the table then.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `not exists` to me:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from customerusers cu
                  where cu.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and cu.EmailAddress is not null
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.CustomerId,
        c.EmailAddress
FROM dbo.Customers c
WHERE CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId
                         FROM dbo.CustomerUsers
                         WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
                         AND CustomerId IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

this helps:

```
SELECT CustomerId
FROM CustomerUsers
Group by CustomerId
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN EmailAddress IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: can you explain why?